# "(int)Math.ceil(double)" always return 1, even when the value is greater than 1

Tags: java, casting, int, double, rounding

I'm creating an Android app and I need to calculate the movement speed of the device. I do this by taking an average of some earlier locations' speeds.
However, I need the speed to be in `km/h` as an `int`, so I use

```java
(int)Math.ceil(speedAsDouble)
```

However, this always equal to `1`, even if the `speedAsDouble` is `7.8825246` or `0.58178`.
This is the relevant part of the code:

```java
// Create a variable for the speed
double speedAsDouble = 0d;

// Loop through the last points
for(int i = 0; i < lastPoints.size() - 1; i++)
{
    // Add the speed for the current point to the total speed
    speedAsDouble += (double)(lastPoints.get(i).distanceTo(lastPoints.get(i + 1)) / (lastPoints.get(i + 1).getTime() - lastPoints.get(i).getTime()));
}

// Divide the speed by the number of points
speedAsDouble /= (double)lastPoints.size();
// Convert the speed to km/h
speedAsDouble *= 3.6d;

// Log the speed
System.out.println("Speed: " + speedAsDouble);
```

I then round the number and cast it to an int as described above using

```
int speedAsInt = (int)Math.ceil(speedAsDouble)
```

and log the number again with

```
System.out.println("Rounded speed: " + speedAsInt)
```

Here is a part of the log:

```
05-17 12:00:42.605  24610-24610/package I/System.out﹕ Speed: 0.0
05-17 12:00:42.635  24610-24610/package I/System.out﹕ Rounded speed: 0
05-17 12:00:43.625  24610-24610/package I/System.out﹕ Speed: 7.026718463748694E-4
05-17 12:00:43.645  24610-24610/package I/System.out﹕ Rounded speed: 1
05-17 12:00:44.595  24610-24610/package I/System.out﹕ Speed: 5.27003884781152E-4
05-17 12:00:44.615  24610-24610/package I/System.out﹕ Rounded speed: 1
05-17 12:00:45.595  24610-24610/package I/System.out﹕ Speed: 4.216031078249216E-4
05-17 12:00:45.635  24610-24610/package I/System.out﹕ Rounded speed: 1
05-17 12:00:46.595  24610-24610/package I/System.out﹕ Speed: 0.002668234216980636
05-17 12:00:46.605  24610-24610/package I/System.out﹕ Rounded speed: 1
```

I've spent much time looking at this, trying different variable types and casting variables but with no success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all the outputs you printed (except the first one which is 0) `Speed` is smaller than 1 (`7.026718463748694E-4`, `5.27003884781152E-4`, etc...). Notice the negative exponent.

Therefore it's no wonder `ceil` returns 1.

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12 notice the negative exponent `E-4`

Comment: Sorry, I'm only 14, and we've not learned about exponents in school yet. I thought it meant something else.

Comment: A negative exponent means the number is less than 1.

Comment: @TheDDestroyer12 Don't apologize, asking questions isn't wrong. It is very good habit.

Answer (score 1):

Please look more carefully at your output, for example:

`05-17 12:00:43.625  24610-24610/package I/System.out﹕ Speed: 7.026718463748694E-4`

doesn't mean you have 7.02, but 0.000702. There is `E-4` at the end. When you would use ceil it will always return 1.